# XPath Search inside span class following a specific text inside a li

Tags: xpath

I would like to find "How are you?" using xpath with this part of html :

```
<li>Hello<span class="redS bold">How are you ?</span></li
```

I tried with :

```
//span[contains(@class, 'redS bold') and text() = 'Hello']
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `//span[contains(text(),'How are you')]`  ? or `//span[contains(@class,'redS bold') and contains(text(),'How are you')]` ?

Comment: Try `//li[starts-with(., "Hello")]/span/text()`

Comment: Tried //li[starts-with(., "Hello")]/span/text() but not working, many thanks

Comment: If it's *not working*, then it's not an XPath issue... Which tool do you use? Share your code

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
//span[contains(text(),'How are you')]
```

? or maybe

```
//span[contains(@class,'redS bold') and contains(text(),'How are you')]
```